# Документация к логической структуре базы данных для SEDE и дампа данных

Tags: поддержка, faq, data-dump, data-explorer

Приблизительно каждые три месяца Stack Overflow выкладывает на [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) «дамп данных» с открытым содержимым сайтов сети Stack Exchange. В дополнение, данные доступны для выполнения динамических запроса на [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com) (SEDE). По мере добавления на сайты Stack Exchange новой функциональности, схема данных может меняться.

Какова текущая, актуальная структура общедоступного дампа данных?

---

<sub>Это перевод публикации «[Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/)»</sub>

Answer (score 8):

### Posts

- `Id`
- `PostTypeId` (Значения из таблицы типов сообщений [`PostTypes`](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36599/show-all-types))

  1. Вопрос
  2. Ответ
  3. Потерянное описание метки
  4. Краткое описание метки
  5. Описание метки
  6. Номинация в модераторы
  7. Поле для заполнения описания (похоже, только для [описание выборов в модераторы](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8041931/body))
  8. Описание привилегии
- `AcceptedAnswerId` (Присутствует если только `PostTypeId = 1`)
- `ParentID` (Присутствует если только `PostTypeId = 2`)
- `CreationDate`
- `DeletionDate` (Только не нулевые значение для таблицы SEDE `PostsWithDeleted`. Удаленные сообщения в `Posts` не входят; столбец в выгруженных данных отсутствует.)
- `Score`
- `ViewCount` (Может быть нулем)
- `Body` ( [Готовый к просмотру HTML](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51177/include-markdown-post-bodies-in-the-data-dump), не Markdown)
- `OwnerUserId` (Присутствует только если участник не был удален; всегда -1 для описаний метки, т.e. автором является Дух сообщества)
- `OwnerDisplayName` (Может быть нулем)
- `LastEditorUserId` (Может быть нулем)
- `LastEditorDisplayName` (Может быть нулем).
- `LastEditDate`="2009-03-05T22:28:34.823" – дата и время последней правки сообщения (может быть нулем)
- `LastActivityDate`="2009-03-11T12:51:01.480" – дата и время последней активности в сообщении. Для вопроса это может быть правка сообщения, публикация нового ответа, начало нового конкурса и т.п.
- `Title` (Может быть нулем)
- `Tags` (Может быть нулем)
- `AnswerCount` (Может быть нулем)
- `CommentCount`
- `FavoriteCount`
- `ClosedDate` (Присутствует, только если сообщение закрыто)
- `CommunityOwnedDate` (Присутствует, только если сообщение было отмечено общим)

### Users

- `Id`
- `Reputation`
- `CreationDate`
- `DisplayName`
- `LastAccessDate`
- `WebsiteUrl`
- `Location`
- `AboutMe`
- `Views`
- `UpVotes` ([Сколько очков рейтинга было присуждено участником](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260897/what-is-upvotes-of-users-in-database-schema-documentation))
- `DownVotes`
- `EmailHash`
- `AccountId` (Идентификатор учётной записи в сети StackExchange)
- `Age`

### Comments

- `Id` ()
- [`PostId`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/472607/information-schema-for-a-table?table=posts)
- `Score` (Присутствует, только если рейтинг > 0)
- `Text` – например: "@Stu Thompson: What a horrible idea, you clueless git!"
- `CreationDate` – например: "2008-09-06T08:07:10.730"
- `UserDisplayName`
- `UserId` (Опционально. Отсутствует, если участник был удален.)

### Badges

- `Id`
- `UserId` – например: "420"
- `Name`
- `Date`  – например: "2008-09-15T08:55:03.923"
- `Class` («Класс»), 1 – «Золото», 2 – «Серебро», 3 – «Бронза».
- `TagBased` – истинно, если  знак относится к метке, в противном случае – именованный знак.

### CloseAsOffTopicReasonTypes («Закрыть по причине несоответствия теме»)

- `Id`
- `IsUniversal`
- `MarkdownMini` — текст с указанием причины закрытия в markdown-синтаксисе.
- `CreationDate`
- `CreationModeratorId`
- `ApprovalDate`
- `ApprovalModeratorId`
- `DeactivationDate`
- `DeactivationModeratorId`

### PendingFlags («Отложенные флаги»)

Несмотря на название, эта таблица фактически содержит взаимосвязанные флаги и баллы голосования.

- `Id`
- `FlagTypeId` (Из таблицы типов флагов [`FlagTypes`](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36599/show-all-types))

  13. Шаблонный флаг закрытия
  14. Голос за закрытие
  15. Голос за повторное открытие
- `PostId`
- `CreationDate`
- `CloseReasonTypeId` (Из таблицы типов причин закрытия [`CloseReasonTypes`](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36599/show-all-types))
- `CloseAsOffTopicReasonTypeId` – если `CloseReasonTypeId = 102 (off-topic)` (из таблицы типов причин закрытия за несоответствие теме [`CloseAsOffTopicReasonTypes`](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36599/show-all-types))
- `DuplicateOfQuestionId` Если `CloseReasonTypeId` = 1 или 101 (старый дублирующийся или текущий дублирующийся вопрос)
- `BelongsOnBaseHostAddress` (Для голосов за закрытие и перенос)

### PostFeedback

- `Id`
- `PostId`
- `IsAnonymous`
- `VoteTypeId`
- `CreationDate`

### PostHistory

- `Id`
- `PostHistoryTypeId` (Из таблицы типов историй сообщений [`PostHistoryTypes`](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36599/show-all-types))

  1. Initial Title – первый заголовок вопроса
  2. Initial Body – первый необработанный текст, с которым был опубликован вопрос
  3. Initial Tags – первые метки, с которыми был опубликован вопрос
  4. Edit Title – изменения в названии вопроса
  5. Edit Body – изменения в тексте вопроса, необработанный текст, сохраненный в markdown-формате
  6. Edit Tags – изменения в метках вопроса
  7. Rollback Title – заголовок вопроса был возвращен к предыдущему состоянию
  8. Rollback Body – текст сообщения был возвращен к предыдущему состоянию – здесь хранится необработанный текст
  9. Rollback Tags – метки вопроса были возвращены к предыдущему состоянию. 
  10. Post Closed – по результатам голосования, сообщение должно быть закрыто
  11. Post Reopened – по результатам голосования, сообщение должно быть повторно открыто
  12. Post Deleted - по результатам голосования, сообщение должно быть удалено
  13. Post Undeleted - по результатам голосования, сообщение должно быть восстановлено
  14. Post Locked – сообщение было заблокировано модератором
  15. Post Unlocked – сообщение было разблокировано модератором
  16. Community Owned – сообщение стало общим
  17. Post Migrated – сообщение было перемещено, *в данный момент заменено на пункты 35 и 36*
  18. Question Merged – произошло слияние вопроса с другим, ранее удаленным вопросом
  19. Question Protected – вопрос под защитой модератора
  20. Question Unprotected – с вопроса была снята защита модератора
  21. Post Disassociated – администратор удалил OwnerUserId сообщения
  22. Question Unmerged – для вопроса, над которым было проведено слияние, были восстановлены ответы и рейтинг
  24. Suggested Edit Applied
  25. Post Tweeted
  31. Comment discussion moved to chat
  33. Post notice added
  34. Post notice removed
  35. Post migrated away
  36. Post migrated here
  37. Post merge source
  38. Post merge destination
- `PostId`
- `RevisionGUID`. Иногда одному действию соответствует несколько типов записи в истории сообщения. Все они будут сгруппированы под одним и тем же RevisionGUID
- `CreationDate` – например, "2009-03-05T22:28:34.823"
- `UserId`
- `UserDisplayName` – заполнено, если участник был удален и больше не определяется по идентификатору участника.
- `Comment` – это поле будет содержать комментарий участника, редактирующего сообщение. Если `PostHistoryTypeId = 10`, это поле содержит `CloseReasonId` причины закрытия (входящей в `CloseReasonTypes`):
  **Старые причины закрытия:** 
  1: Exact Duplicate 
  2: Off-topic 
  3: Subjective and argumentative 
  4: Not a real question 
  7: Too localized 
  10: General reference 
  20: Noise or pointless (Только для Меты) 
  **Текущие причины закрытия:** 
  101: Duplicate 
  102: Off-topic 
  103: Unclear what you're asking 
  104: Too broad 
  105: Primarily opinion-based
- `Text` – необработанный текст актуального значения для текущей версии

  - Если PostHistoryTypeId = 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 или 15, этот столбец будет содержать строку в кодировке JSON со списком всех пользователей, проголосовавших за PostHistoryTypeId
  - Если речь идет о двойном голосовании за закрытие, строка JSON будет содержать массив ID оригинальных вопросов `OriginalQuestionIds`
  - Если PostHistoryTypeId = 17, этот столбец будет содержать данные о перемещении: URL, откуда происходит перенос или URL, куда осуществляется перенос

### PostLinks

- `Id` – первичный ключ
- `CreationDate` – время создания ссылки
- `PostId` – идентификатор исходного сообщения
- `RelatedPostId` – идентификатор целевого/связанного сообщения
- `LinkTypeId` – тип ссылки

  1. Связано
  3. Дублируется

### PostsWithDeleted

Аналогична таблице Posts, но содержит также и удаленные сообщения. Для удаленных сообщений существует дополнительный столбец `Deletiondate` (не нулевой). Поля, содержащие информацию, когда `DeletionDate` не нулевой:

- Id
- PostTypeId
- ParentId – только если PostTypeId = 2 (ответ)
- CreationDate
- DeletionDate

### PostTags

- `PostId`
- `TagId`

### ReviewRejectionReasons

Шаблонные причины отклонения предлагаемых правок. См. [Показать все причины отклонения правок](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/199800/show-all-review-rejection-reasons)

- `Id`
- `Name`
- `Description`
- `PostTypeId`

### ReviewTaskResults

- `Id`
- `ReviewTaskId`
- [`ReviewTaskResultTypeId`](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36599/show-all-types)

  1. Not Sure
  2. Approve – относительно предлагаемых правок
  3. Reject – относительно предлагаемых правок
  4. Delete – низкое качество
  5. Edit – первые сообщения, поздние ответы, низкое качество
  6. Close – закрыть, низкое качество
  7. Looks OK – низкое качество
  8. Do Not Close – закрыть
  9. Recommend Deletion – ответ низкого качества
  10. Recommend Close – вопрос низкого качества
  11. I'm Done – первые сообщения
  12. Reopen – открыть повторно
  13. Leave Closed – открыть повторно
  14. Edit and Reopen – открыть повторно
  15. Excellent – оценка сообщества
  16. Satisfactory – оценка сообщества
  17. Needs Improvement – оценка сообщества
  18. No Action Needed – первые сообщения, поздние ответы
- `CreationDate`
- `RejectionReasonId` – для предлагаемых правок, указанные в `ReviewRejectionReasons`
- `Comment`

### ReviewTasks

- `Id`
- [`ReviewTaskTypeId`[1](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36599/show-all-types))

  1. Suggested Edit
  2. Close Votes
  3. Low Quality Posts
  4. First Post
  5. Late Answer
  6. Reopen Vote
  7. Community Evaluation
  8. Link Validation
  9. Flagged Posts
  10. Triage
  11. Helper
- `CreationDate`
- `DeletionDate`
- [`ReviewTaskStateId`](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/199801/show-all-review-task-states))

  1. Active
  2. Completed
  3. Invalidated
- `PostId`
- `SuggestedEditId` – идентификатор предлагаемых правок, для которых, по исторически сложившимся причинам, предусмотрена собственная нумерация
- `CompletedByReviewTaskId`

### SuggestedEdits

- `Id`
- `PostId`
- `CreationDate`
- `ApprovalDate`
- `RejectionDate`
- `OwnerUserId`
- `Comment`
- `Text`
- `Title`
- `Tags`
- `RevisionGUID`

### SuggestedEditVotes

- `Id`
- `SuggestedEditId`
- `UserId`
- `VoteTypeId` – 2 – Approval, 3 – Reject
- `CreationDate`
- `TargetUserId`
- `TargetRepChange`

### Tags

- `Id`
- `TagName`
- `Count`
- `ExcerptPostId`
- `WikiPostId`

### TagSynonyms

- `Id`
- `SourceTagName`
- `TargetTagName`
- `CreationDate`
- `OwnerUserId`
- `AutoRenameCount`
- `LastAutoRename`
- `Score`
- `ApprovedByUserId`
- `ApprovalDate`

### Votes

- `Id`
- `PostId`
- [`VoteTypeId`](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36599/show-all-types)

  1. AcceptedByOriginator
  2. UpMod – [а–ля голос «за»](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157536/200117)
  3. DownMod – [а–ля голос «против»](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157536/200117)
  4. Offensive
  5. Favorite – также будет заполнено поле UserId
  6. Close – с 2013-06-25 голоса за закрытие хранятся ТОЛЬКО в таблице
  7. Reopen
  8. BountyStart – также будут заполнены поля UserId и BountyAmount
  9. BountyClose – также будет заполнено поле BountyAmount
  10. Deletion
  11. Undeletion
  12. Spam
  15. ModeratorReview
  16. ApproveEditSuggestion
- `UserId` – присутствует, только если VoteTypeId = 5 или 8.
- `CreationDate` – [данные о времени удалены сознательно](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/933/163250) в целях соблюдения конфиденциальности участников
- `BountyAmount` – присутствует, только если VoteTypeId = 8 или 9

### xxxTypes

Не указаны: таблицы `xxxTypes`, в которых содержатся пары (Id, Name) для `Posts.PostTypeId`, `Votes.VoteTypeId`, и т. д.. См. [«Показать все типы»](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36599/show-all-types).

Comment: В PostHistory нумерация не сплошная. Так и должно быть?

Comment: @NickVolynkin На сколько я понимаю, да.