# Отфильтровать вопросы/ответы по определённой метке

Tags: поддержка, вопросы

Можно ли как-то посмотреть по определённой метке:

1. список вопросов с наибольшим рейтингом за последние N дней
2. список ответов с наибольшим рейтингом за последние N дней
3. список конкурсных вопросов (но не текущих, а уже завершившихся) за
   последние N дней (или за всё время)

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

С большой вероятностью, частично, вам подойдет встроенный поиск (более подробно про возможности фильтров в справочном центре «[Как выполнять поиск?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/searching)»).

1. Да. Запрос: `[c#] created:2d.. is:question`.
2. Да. Запрос: `[c#] created:2d.. is:answer`.
3. В общем случае, выполнить поиск через интерфейс сайта нельзя. Все же, есть несколько опций.

   - [Вкладка конкурсных вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured), для просмотра открытых конкурсов.
   - Выборка текущих конкурсных вопросов через встроенный поиск. Запрос: `hasnotice:1 is:question locked:0`.
   - Для выборки конкурсных вопросов можно воспользоваться [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3226/6) ([возможный вариант запроса](http://data.stackexchange.com/ru/query/538220/200---)).
   - Также вы можете воспользоваться Stack Exchange API ([пример запроса](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269020/274323)).