# Можно ли улучшить навигацию в своих ответах (в профиле)?

Tags: предложение

Мой ответ на вопрос иногда важен для меня (я публикую такое решение которое мне может понадобится в будущем), а иногда это просто ответ, который для меня менее важен. Сейчас у меня 83 ответа на трёх закладках. Я помню что ответ на мой вопрос есть в одной из трёх, можно ли сделать:

1. Или поделить ответы на две категории (мои избранные, и другие).
2. Или поиск по словам в заголовках ответов (фильтр, желательно активный). По поводу поиска сложно, потому что не всегда заголовок "вопроса" совпадает с названием решения.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте стандартный механизм поиска. Заходите в свой профиль и видите, что поиск уже ограничен вашими ответами и вопросами:

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/213987/a-k

> [image: Профиль пользователя]

Вы можете добавить либо метку языка и посмотреть все ваши вопросы по метке (на эту же страницу можно зайти со страницы "метки" вашего профиля), либо добавить уточняющие слова поиска.

> [image: Поиск]

Дополнительно можете посмотреть следующие страницы:

- [Как искать вопросы с определенными метками?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3408/213987)
- [Отфильтровать вопросы/ответы по определённой метке](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3696/213987)
- [справка по расширенному поиску](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

Уверяю вас, этот поиск очень эффективен. Пользуйтесь и вам не понадобится просить какой-то дополнительный функционал, типа фильтров-кнопочек и прочего.

Comment: Вместо явного указания собственного `id` можно использовать `me`.

Comment: Тогда уж так: [`user:me infavorites:mine`](//ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+infavorites%3Amine). Но таким образом находятся только вопросы, но не ответы.

Comment: @Qwertiy Да, тут либо `is:answer` добавлять, либо `infavorites:mine` (ведь в избранное добавляются не ответы, а вопросы). В любом случае, я думаю, что посыл моего ответа очевиден: нужно использовать возможности расширенного поиска, их вполне хватает для решения типовых задач. И ничего допиливать в функциональности ruso не нужно.

Comment: А я за то, чтоб дописать))